# Seasonality in data

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I have two monthly series - number of people employed and number of people unemployed.

Both the series are not seasonal candidates, i.e., they don't have seasonality.

I also have access to these two series at the weekly level. Then should I just assume that if a series is not a seasonal candidate at the monthly level, then it won't be a seasonal candidate at the weekly level?

Comment: Were these time series deseasonalized in advance? Often this kind of data comes from instance that deseasonalize the time series themselves.

Comment: No, these series are not seasonally adjusted. These series contain only raw data obtained through a household survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lack of seasonality at the monthly level need not imply a lack of seasonality at the weekly level. Layoffs may tend to happen at the beginning of the month after missing the prior month's targets. The [BLS paper here](https://www.bls.gov/osmr/research-papers/2014/pdf/ec140040.pdf) discusses handling weekly seasonality even after adjusting for monthly seasonality.